# django facebook and user password authentication

Tags: django, authentication

i am new in django, i require login with user and password or facebook, i am using rest framework for api endpoints. ¿How i can do it?

i try with:

django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 but don't work for my because i needs save additional info from user after first enter.

I expect have 2 endpoint one sending user and password and another sending facebook auth token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's sample code for user login for Django Rest Framework:

```
class Login(APIView):

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Login, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        request_data = JSONParser().parse(request)

        if 'email' in request_data and 'password' in request_data:
            try:
                validate_email(request_data['email'])
            except ValidationError:
                return JsonResponse({'result': 'E-mail is invalid'}, status=400)

            user = authenticate(email=request_data['email'], password=request_data['password'])

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    try:
                        token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
                    except Token.DoesNotExist:
                        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

                    return JsonResponse({'result': 'success', 'token': token.key, 'id': user.id}, status=200)

            return JsonResponse({'result': 'E-mail or password is incorrect'}, status=400)

        return JsonResponse({'result': 'E-mail or password is empty'}, status=400)
```

Here's sample for FB login code for Django Rest Framework (from my test project):

```
class FbLogin(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FbLogin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        request_data = JSONParser().parse(request)

        if 'access_token' in request_data:
            response = requests.get(
                url='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/',
                params={
                    'access_token': request_data['access_token'],
                    'fields': 'email,first_name,last_name',
                },
            )

            json_response = json.loads(response.text)

            if 'error' not in json_response:
                response_photo = requests.get(
                    url='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/%s/picture' % json_response['id'],
                    params={
                        'redirect': 'false',
                        'type': 'large',
                    },
                )
                response_photo_json = json.loads(response_photo.text)

                response_friends = requests.get(
                    url='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/friends/',
                    params={
                        'access_token': request_data['access_token'],
                        'limit': 300,
                    },
                )

                generated_password = get_random_string(10, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
                try:
                    json_response_email = json_response['email']
                except:
                    first_name = json_response['first_name'].lower()
                    last_name = json_response['last_name'].lower()
                    id = json_response['id']
                    json_response_email = first_name + last_name + id + '@facebook.com'
                try:
                    current_user = User.objects.get(email=json_response_email)
                    current_user.set_password(generated_password)
                    current_user.save()
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    new_user = User.objects.create_user(email=json_response_email,
                                                        password=generated_password)

                    new_user.provider_id = json_response['id']
                    new_user.provider_type = 'facebook'

                    if 'first_name' in json_response:
                        new_user.first_name = json_response['first_name']

                    if 'last_name' in json_response:
                        new_user.last_name = json_response['last_name']

                    new_user.save()

                    photo_name = urlparse(response_photo_json['data']['url']).path.split('/')[-1].split('?')[-1]
                    photo_content = urllib.request.urlretrieve(response_photo_json['data']['url'])

                    new_user.profile_photo.save(photo_name, File(open(photo_content[0], 'rb')), save=True)
                user = authenticate(email=json_response_email, password=generated_password)
                try:
                    token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
                except Token.DoesNotExist:
                    token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                            fullname = json_response['first_name'] + ' ' + json_response['last_name']
                            return JsonResponse({'result': 'success', 'token': token.key, 'name': fullname}, status=200)

            return JsonResponse({'result': 'User access token is incorrect'}, status=400)
```